# Function in array executed before calling it

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an array like this:

```
$cmds = array(
'info' => call_user_func('_info', $cmd1),
'e1' => 'something'
);
```

The func itself:

```
function _info($cmd1){
if(strlen($cmd1) < 2){
die('Invalid Username');
}else{
echo 'cmd1 > 2';}
}
```

The problem is it being executed before i call it giving undefined variable error because `$cmd1` not exist yet, it will be exist when i call it in a `foreach` function.
Been searching for a solution for hours but didn't find.
I tried setting the `array` as this `'info' => _info($cmd1)` and `'info' => '_info'` and putted `$cmd1` directly in the func like this

```
function _info(){
if(strlen($cmd1) < 2){die('invalid');
}
```

But i still get the same error as it being called before i want to be.

Comment: call_user_func will always fire when it gets parsed. And: the strlen comparison won't work as "el" has a strlen of exactly 2 and you are challenging against less than 2.

Comment: I don't compare with e1 array key i do with $cmd1 that is another var and e1 is just to make array more real as its not my original array, my original array has more that 20 keys and values

Comment: Be that as it may, you need to drop the call_user_func.

Comment: I tried to set it as 'info' => _info($cmd1) it still calling it when i don't want it to be done

Comment: So how should i make it to be called only when i call it in foreach func?

Comment: Of course it gets called. The PHP parser reads: "oh look, there is a key in an array which will get the value of _info($cmd1)". Best way to achieve what you want to achieve is to call the function the moment you need it to be run. When looping through an array or whatever your code does IRL

Comment: Is there anyway i can get this done?

Comment: As mentioned above: call _info the moment you need it to be called. Don't store it inside the cmds array.

Comment: What is the programming task you are trying to solve? Why are you storing commands? If we understand your problem maybe we can come to a better solution.

Comment: Its a chat script, that part is when user type a command like /info [username] to get another user info the array carries the commands and its functions, i get commands by  $cmd = explode(' ',$msg) so command will be $cmd[0], $cmd[1], etc.

Comment: call_user_func_array() solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send parameters to be executed later

```
$cmds = array(
    'info' => [ '_info', '$cmd1' ], // single quotes
    'e1'   => 'something'
);
```

In the meantime your cmd1 is defined

```
$cmd1 = "hello";

foreach ($cmds as $key => $cmdset) {
    if (!is_array($cmdset)) {
        // do something with e1 => something
    } else {
        $function = array_shift($cmdset);
        foreach ($cmdset as &$param) {
            // Only variables are treated below, values are passed through as is
            if (stripos($param, '$') === 0) {
                // Remove $
                $cmd1 = substr($param, 1);
                // Set param to the value of cmd1
                $param = $$param; // variable varaible $$
            }
        }
        call_user_func_array($function, $cmdset);
    }
}
```

While this works it is really bad practice to do like this. Depending on a variable function that is not clear if it is set or not. The code is hard to understand.

You should think about another solution where you can ensure that `$cmd1` is set or can be retrieved and if it is not have some way to deal with that as well.

Comment: as you see i make sure it being set, part of foreach func: `if(isset($cmd[1])){ $cmd1=$cmd[0] }else{$cmd1='';}` thats why i check if `$cmd1 < 2`